# Looking for a right angled connector for my 15" Touchbar MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, thunderbolt, hardware-recommendation

Currently I have an LG Ultra Fine 5K Display and a MacBook Pro with TouchBar.  I have one cable connecting my laptop to the monitor that takes care of power, display and USB.  I'm using the cable that came with the monitor.

I'm looking for either a right angle connector or a cable with one right angled connector that does all of the above.

I've tried the [Goliton? 90 Degree Right Angled USB-C USB 3.1 Type-C Male to Female Extension Data Cable for Macbook Tablet - 20CM](http://a.co/1hty1wJ) with no luck

I'd prefer something with this shape but will be happy with any right angle, even if it's a short cable "dongle."  Does such a thing exist and, if so, does anyone have a recommendation?

[image]

Comment: You would be looking for a 90 degree angled Type C DisplayPort or Thunderbolt cable.  I know of none on the market and of the right angled DP products, their quality is extremely poor.  Is there a reason it needs to be right angled?

Comment: What was the issue with the Golitin? cable - was it nonfunctional? There is an [answer](https://www.amazon.com/ask/questions/Tx3VN66R64PDS5S/ref=ask_dp_dpmw_al_hza) on Amazon saying that it does not pass power (though some mention it does...) - was this the issue you had?

Comment: @Allan - Just to help how my desktop setup is.

Comment: @ Scot - Mine got power when I used it but no video at all - I didn't even try the USB hub that's in the monitor